# SwiftUI clear TextField placeholder on focus is working only in a certain way

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to remove the placeholder from a textfield in SwiftUI when user taps on the textfield. So as suggested in stackoverflow i used the following code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ApplicationCore

struct StartUpScreen: View {

    @State var password = ""
    @State var passwordPlaceholder = "Enter Password"
    
    var body: some View {
                        TextField(self.$passwordPlaceholder.wrappedValue, text: $password, onEditingChanged: { (changed) in
                            print("Password onEditingChanged - \(changed)")
                            switch changed {
                            case true:
                                self.$passwordPlaceholder.wrappedValue
                                = self.$password.wrappedValue
                                self.$password.wrappedValue = ""
                            case false:
                                break
                            }
                        })
}
}
```

But when i run it nothing happens. The placeholder remains as it is when the user taps on the TextField box. So i just changed this line

```
self.$password.wrappedValue = ""
```

to this

```
self.$password.wrappedValue = " "
```

and it worked. So the answer i found in stackoverflow was wrong although everyone voted up for it so i thought it should work for me as well. Moreover the weird thing is that although i enter a space to work i do not see any spaces in my TextField and everything works great.

...but i want to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Is there any logic explanation behind all this? Any help appreciated.